# How to send multiple sensor data from arduino to the raspberry pi, and from there to google docs

Tags: raspbian, server, sensor, arduino

I want to build a arduino- based weather station, now I want to know how I can send sensor data from the arduino uno to the raspberry pi and from there to a spreadsheet in gdocs. My problem is, that I use sensors with different communication protocols. (digital, analog and IC2)
I use these sensors:
[light sensor](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Digital_Light_Sensor) [temperature and humidity sensor](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Temperature_and_Humidity_Sensor_Pro) [uv sensor](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_UV_Sensor) [barometer sensor](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Barometer_Sensor)

these are all connected to the arduino uno via the grove base shield:
[base shield](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Base_Shield_V1.3)

Later I want to add a self build rain and wind sensor.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might want to split this into two questions: (1) how to send data from the arduino to the Raspberry Pi, and (2) how to send data to Google docs.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the google drive API.

I don't have any code to hand unfortunately, but you can find code samples, tutorials, API docs and all the usual stuff right here

https://developers.google.com/drive/

I was playing with it all a little while ago, not on my rPI but just in general.

You used to have to use the gDocs API directly for a sheet, now everything is done via GDrive.

If memory serves me correctly, there's a lot of toolkits ready to go on NPM, so put your uploader together in JS code and run it under NodeJS and you should be up and running in next to no time.

Comment: This might help: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/write-google-spreadsheet-from-python/

Answer (score 0):

You have also two different questions on the arduino part - how to Interface several sensors to (presumably) one board and how to interface that (or those) board(s) to a raspberry. For interfacing the arduino to the raspberry, you have at least four different choises  - described in what I feel is increasing difficulty and price:

- hanging the arduino on the usb-port of the raspberry, using Serial.print() to send your data
- using i2c
- Using nrf24 wireless modules
- connecting using tp-networking (via a networking shield or module on the arduino side)

In the tree last cases, you need to have a separate power supply on the arduino.

(to interface several sensors on one arduino, you just connect them using different analog or digital ports and read them after turn in the loop() - for details, ask a question on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)